# Film with an earthquake that creates a chasm in a supermarket aisle

Tags: story-identification, movie

The only scene I remember from this movie is that some character is in the aisles of a supermarket, when suddenly, some earthquake, or something happens, causing the floor in between the aisles to break down, creating a huge chasm in the supermarket aisle. Do you remember what this movie was called?

Answer (score 17):

This is *[2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_(film))*

> In 2009, American geologist Adrian Helmsley visits astrophysicist Satnam Tsurutani in India and learns that an exotic new type of neutrinos from a huge solar flare are heating Earth's core. In Washington, D.C., Helmsley presents his information to White House Chief of Staff Carl Anheuser, who brings him to meet U.S. President Thomas Wilson.
>
> In 2010, Wilson and other world leaders begin a secret project to ensure humanity's survival. China and the G8 nations begin building nine arks, each capable of carrying 100,000 people, in the Himalayas near Cho Ming, Tibet. Nima, a Buddhist monk, is evacuated and his brother Tenzin joins the ark project. Funding is raised by secretly selling tickets at €1 billion per person. By 2011, articles of value are moved to the arks with the help of art expert and First Daughter Laura Wilson.
>
> In 2012, struggling Manhattan Beach, California-based science-fiction writer Jackson Curtis is a chauffeur for Russian billionaire Yuri Karpov. Jackson's former wife Kate and their children Noah and Lilly live with Kate's boyfriend, plastic surgeon and amateur pilot Gordon Silberman. Jackson takes Noah and Lilly camping in Yellowstone National Park. When they enter an area fenced off by the United States Army, they are caught and brought to Adrian, who has read Jackson's books. After being released they meet conspiracy theorist Charlie Frost, who hosts a radio show from the park.
>
> That night, after the military evacuates Yellowstone, Jackson watches Charlie's video of Charles Hapgood's theory that polar shifts and the Mesoamerican Long Count calendar predict a 2012 phenomenon and the end of the world. Charlie reveals that anyone attempting to inform the public was or will be killed. After Jackson and his children return home, earthquakes begin in California. Jackson rents a private plane and rescues his family as the Earth-crust displacement begins, causing a 10.9 magnitude earthquake. Jackson and his family escape Los Angeles as much of the city collapses into the Pacific Ocean....

### The supermarket scene

> Pranks no more, things got real. A negligible surface crack caused the destruction of a medium-sized supermarket. It surely was a miracle that no one got hurt or killed during the occurrence. Now when will this happen the same to your home and spoil your long-prepared supper?

Found with a search for `disaster film supermarket`

Comment: It's funny, I thought about this even though I didn't watch the movie.

Comment: Worth noting that just before the quake strikes, the couple are having a bit of a tiff and the guy says, "I get the feeling something is pulling us apart..." Cue: earthquake.

Comment: @OscarBravo - It wasn't the greatest film, but that line may have been the low water mark. ;-)

Comment: thank you very much, I have been thinking about this scene for literal years, and only now did I find where it was from